# Ruby save Excel as CSV

Tags: ruby

I am trying to go through each .xls file in a directory and save a .csv for each file. I am working with the 'roo' gem and am seeing some errors. Totally open to other approaches, I just need to keep this in Ruby without moving to Ruby on Rails. I am running Ruby 1.9.2 and executing in terminal on a Mac.

Code so far:

```
#! /usr/bin/ruby

require 'roo'


# change excel files to csv
begin
    Dir["/tmp/*.xls"].each do |file|  
      file_path = "#{file}"
      file_basename = File.basename(file, ".xls")
      xls = Excel.new(file_path)
      xls.to_csv = ("/tmp/#{file_basename}.csv")
    end
end
```

And here is the error I get: (line numbers are not the same as example, line 27 is begin statement)

```
/Users/pierce/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/roo-1.10.1/lib/roo/excel.rb:284:in `platform_specific_iconv': uninitialized constant Excel::Iconv (NameError)
    from /Users/pierce/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/roo-1.10.1/lib/roo/excel.rb:277:in `normalize_string'
    from /Users/pierce/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/roo-1.10.1/lib/roo/excel.rb:139:in `block in sheets'
    from /Users/pierce/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/roo-1.10.1/lib/roo/excel.rb:139:in `collect'
    from /Users/pierce/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/roo-1.10.1/lib/roo/excel.rb:139:in `sheets'
    from /Users/pierce/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/roo-1.10.1/lib/roo/excel.rb:123:in `initialize'
    from excel_conversion_test.rb:32:in `new'
    from excel_conversion_test.rb:32:in `block in <main>'
    from excel_conversion_test.rb:28:in `each'
    from excel_conversion_test.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

As suggested I tried to install inconv and got the following errors:

```
ERROR:  Error installing iconv:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/pierce/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for iconv() in iconv.h... no
checking for iconv() in -liconv... yes
checking for const of iconv() 2nd argument... no
creating Makefile

make
/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -I. -I/Users/pierce/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.2.0 -I/Users/pierce/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/Users/pierce/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -I'/Users/pierce/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/include'  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -fno-common -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-long-long  -pipe  -o iconv.o -c iconv.c
In file included from iconv.c:21:
/Users/pierce/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward/st.h:2:2: warning: #warning use "ruby/st.h" instead of bare "st.h"
iconv.c:22:20: error: intern.h: No such file or directory
iconv.c: In function ‘map_charset’:
iconv.c:139: error: ‘struct RHash’ has no member named ‘tbl’
iconv.c:139: error: ‘struct RHash’ has no member named ‘tbl’
iconv.c:142: error: ‘struct RHash’ has no member named ‘tbl’
iconv.c: In function ‘iconv_create’:
iconv.c:187: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘len’
iconv.c:188: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘len’
iconv.c:190: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘ptr’
iconv.c:190: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘ptr’
iconv.c:190: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘ptr’
iconv.c:190: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘ptr’
iconv.c:192: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘ptr’
iconv.c:193: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘len’
iconv.c: In function ‘iconv_fail’:
iconv.c:328: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘len’
iconv.c: In function ‘iconv_fail_retry’:
iconv.c:352: error: ‘ruby_errinfo’ undeclared (first use in this function)
iconv.c:352: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
iconv.c:352: error: for each function it appears in.)
iconv.c: In function ‘rb_str_derive’:
iconv.c:371: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘ptr’
iconv.c:371: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘len’
iconv.c:373: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘ptr’
iconv.c:373: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘len’
iconv.c:374: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘ptr’
iconv.c: In function ‘iconv_convert’:
iconv.c:418: error: ‘struct RArray’ has no member named ‘len’
iconv.c:418: error: ‘struct RArray’ has no member named ‘ptr’
iconv.c:436: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘len’
iconv.c:437: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘ptr’
iconv.c:455: warning: comparison of unsigned expression >= 0 is always true
iconv.c:458: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned
iconv.c:459: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned
iconv.c:491: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
iconv.c:494: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
iconv.c:497: error: ‘struct RArray’ has no member named ‘len’
iconv.c:498: error: ‘struct RArray’ has no member named ‘ptr’
iconv.c:499: error: ‘struct RArray’ has no member named ‘ptr’
iconv.c:501: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘len’
iconv.c:502: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘ptr’
iconv.c:514: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
iconv.c: In function ‘iconv_s_convert’:
iconv.c:615: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘len’
make: *** [iconv.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/pierce/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/iconv-0.1 for inspection.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this: `require 'iconv'` before `require 'roo'`. I found this solution [here](https://github.com/hmcgowan/roo/issues/13), and i got there using this query on google: `roo/excel.rb:284`. An example [here](https://gist.github.com/589717)! Notice about the `=` in this line: `xls.to_csv = ("/tmp/#{file_basename}.csv")` that should not be there.

Comment: Great suggestion. I tried to install iconv and received many errors (added to original question). From what I read, it seems to be a fix for ruby prior to 1.9.

Comment: looking again at ur code i saw the "=" between 'xls.to_csv' and '("/tmp/#{file_basename}.csv")'. Please, can u remove it and try out? Sorry for that, saw only know this problem. Hope it works.

Comment: Yes! Thank you for that. I would probably be a much better developer if I could read and spell.

Answer (score 2):

I decided to post an answer to try and explain this situation for anyone else that arrives here from Google.

As David points out, to fix this error...

```
 uninitialized constant Excel::Iconv
```

...you'll have to require "iconv":

```
require "iconv"
require "roo"
```

This is because the Roo gem calls `Iconv.new` in its internal Excel class but Roo forgot to require "iconv" itself, so you're forced to do it. It's a bug. It's no different than calling `Set.new` without `require "set"`

**Iconv is part of Ruby 1.8 and 1.9's standard library.** You don't install it. It's already there.

However, it's worth pointing out that Iconv is deprecated in Ruby 1.9 and removed in Ruby 2.0.